# Multiple Markers, InfoWindow Against Address API V3

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

**Goal:** I want to display Multiple Markers and InfoWindow against Adress.

Searching got me to this code, shows Multiple Markers and InfoWindow against Lang & Lat
but in my case there will be address array that i have...
What function google provides to convert adress into lat , lang

```
     var markers = [
                      { lat: -33.85, lng: 151.05, name: "marker 1" },
                      { lat: -33.90, lng: 151.10, name: "marker 2" },
                      { lat: -33.95, lng: 151.15, name: "marker 3" },
                      { lat: -33.85, lng: 151.15, name: "marker 4" }
                    ];
               //this puts lat and lng.. but i have array of Address's
               // Create the markers
                for (index in markers) addMarker(markers[index]);
                function addMarker(data) {
                    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                        position: new google.maps.LatLng(data.lat, data.lng),
                        map: map,
                        icon: '/images/shorticon_13.png',
                        title: data.name

                    });
                    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function () {
                        openInfoWindow(marker);
                    });
                }
```

AM newbie to Google maps API v3...
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Geocoding](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geocoding) is the process of converting addresses (like "1600 Amphitheatre Parkway, Mountain View, CA") into geographic coordinates (like latitude 37.423021 and longitude -122.083739), which you can use to place markers or position the map.

If you have more than about 10 addresses, you will run into the rate limit/quota.  For known addresses, it is better to geocode them offline and use the coordinates to display them on page load (like your example).

Comment: @geocoder! thanks dude... am going to read this.. i also try geocoder.getLatLng() funtion to display multiple markers.. but i cant get ... can you please send me any code sample link?

Comment: 1. geocoder.getLatLng() is a Google Maps API v2 method.  2. this is a FAQ, search StackOverflow and/or the Google Maps API v3 group.  There are also lots of good examples in the documentation (the link in my answer).